# Why does $|x-1|\le c$ imply $1-c\le |x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

How can I prove that $|x-1|\le c$ implies $1-c\le |x|$ for complex $x$?

**What I tried**

Let $x$ and $y$ be complex numbers. We have the inequality
$$||x|-|y||\le |x+y|\le |x|+|y|.$$
I got
$$c\ge |x-1|\ge ||x|-1|\ge |x|-1\implies |x|\le 1+c,$$
though this is not quite what I wanted. I tried using $c\ge |x-1|\implies -c\le -|x-1|\ge -(|x|+1)$, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @Bertrand87 $x$ is a *complex* number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$
c\geq|x-1|=|1-x|\geq|1|-|x|=1-|x|\implies |x|\geq 1-c
$$

Answer (score 1):

From $|x-1|\leq c$, you get $|1-x|\leq c$, so $1-|x|\leq c$.

Answer (score 1):

There are always *two* ways to use the left triangle inequality: $$|x+y| \ge |x| - |y|$$ and $$|x+y| \ge |y| - |x| \, . $$

You did $c \ge |x-1| \ge |x| -1 $, which gives $|x| \le 1+c$. That is correct, but not what you are looking for.

With $c \ge |x-1| \ge 1-|x| $ the desired estimate follows.